# When there is 2 object being declared in main method, the code is being compiled simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

I am here investigating multi-thread operation. But I am currently feeling doubt about the main method execution sequence. Please explain to me these, the question is tagged below.

This is a simple program I am investigating

```
public class HelloWorld implements Runnable  {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadname;

    HelloWorld(String name){
        threadname= name;
        System.out.println("Create " +threadname);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running " +threadname);
        try {
            for(int i=4; i>0;i--) {
                System.out.println("Thread" +threadname +", "+i);
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread" +threadname +"interrupted ");
        }
        System.out.println("Thread" +threadname +"exiting ");
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " +threadname);
        if(t==null)
        {
            t=new Thread(this, threadname);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld obj1= new HelloWorld ("Thread-1");
        obj1.start();

        HelloWorld obj2= new HelloWorld ("Thread-2");
        obj2.start();
    }
}
```

actual result

```
Create Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
Create Thread-2
Starting Thread-2
Running Thread-1
ThreadThread-1, 4
Running Thread-2
ThreadThread-2, 4
ThreadThread-2, 3
ThreadThread-1, 3
ThreadThread-1, 2
ThreadThread-2, 2
ThreadThread-1, 1
ThreadThread-2, 1
ThreadThread-2exiting 
ThreadThread-1exiting
```

My question:

```
Create Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
Create Thread-2(why here will switch from 1 to 2)
Starting Thread-2
Running Thread-1
ThreadThread-1, 4
Running Thread-2(At here, I understand the thread is switch when Thread.sleep(50) is being executed;)
ThreadThread-2, 4
ThreadThread-2, 3
ThreadThread-1, 3
ThreadThread-1, 2
ThreadThread-2, 2
ThreadThread-1, 1
ThreadThread-2, 1
ThreadThread-2exiting 
ThreadThread-1exiting
```

Question:why here will switch from 1 to 2?
Is the 2 objects at the main method run simultaneously?

Comment: *Is the 2 objects at the main method run simultaneously* - Yes that it the purpose of `Threads`

Comment: that's what thread are used for: [`The Java Virtual Machine allows an application to have multiple threads of execution running concurrently`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: @ScaryWombat then how the compiler know it is the thread , because at main method there havn't mention about the thread object when compiler first running the obj1

Comment: Look at `HelloWorld`

Comment: Re, " then how the compiler know it is the thread...?" The compiler does _not_ know anything about threads. It only knows about function calls.  Your code calls into the Java standard library when it executes  `t = new Thread(...)`, and then calls `t.start()`.  The real magic happens when the `start()` method asks the operating system to create a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

> This is because you are using multi threading and multi threading
>   provides parallel execution.

In main method you have started two child threads obj1.start() and obj2.start(). Till obj1.start() there is only one child thread (main thread being the parent). But when you start second child thread obj2.start(), now there are two child threads which are being executed parallel that is why switching happened.Both of the thread will have separate path of execution and will run in parallel.

Also, switching is happening because of the thread scheduling algorithm (Round Robin, etc.) being used by CPU.